# How to move ID from outside JSON object to inside?

Tags: python, json, nosql

I'm trying to create a telegram bot for my fantasy football league, but I hit a small snag.
I'm pulling a JSON file that I want to upload to my MongoDB.
The JSON file has the id on the outside of the object:

```
{
    "2103": {
        "years_exp": 1,
        "search_rank": 9999999
}
```

but to be able to pull data from the different collections I have, I would need the id to be on the inside like this:

```
{
     {
        "_id": 2103
        "years_exp": 1,
        "search_rank": 9999999
}
```

I've been trying to parse the file with a dictionary, array, lists and update the JSON file, but I can't figure it out.

Is there a way to convert one format to another?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Given:
data = {'2103': {'years_exp': 1, 'search_rank': 9999999}}

# List comprehension:
# Formats the key as a dictionary and converts it to an integer,
# Combines this new dict with the inner value dict.
data = [{'_id':int(key)}|value for key, value in data.items()]
print(data)
```

Output (Formatted pretty):

```
[
  {
    '_id': 2103, 
    'years_exp': 1, 
    'search_rank': 9999999
  }
]
```

Comment: This seems to work if I have only one object, but doesn't seem to work with the whole file. I was trying to loop it through each object, but I wasn't able to figure that out. I appreciate the help, one step closer to the answer!

Comment: @DaHokeyPokey feel free to share a larger sample that actually replicates your issue...